# Is there anything that should be done to increase security on a new system?

Tags: networking, security, firewall, system-settings, hacking

Let's assume I just installed Ubuntu on a laptop. This laptop may be used in different networks with different security measurements (at home, university, work place).

Is there anything that should be set up to prevent unauthorised system access/data leak or other security breaches, besides using a supported OS version, not installing shady software/repositories and such?

Are there any "hidden" settings regarding remote access or firewall configurations that should be defined to make the system less vulnerable?

Comment: disable stuff you do not need: `samba`, `apache`, `ssh` ( I do not mention `telnet`)

Comment: @LittleByBlue, none of these things come installed out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty broad, but inferring from your first sentence about "different security measurements" for home, etc, I would recommend you try `gufw`

`gufw` is a GUI front-end to the `ufw` firewall and it allows you to create profiles for home, etc.

`sudo apt-get install gufw`

As a simple solution, you can just set the default **Incoming** rule to Deny and default **Outgoing** rule to Allow.  Then add exceptions for incoming on the ports/services you want in each profile.

Comment: Hi Oliver, yes the question was asked that way. I am no network expert and I simply do not know all possibilities of security breaches. You made the correct assumption though - at home, you are able to control the preferences of your router to disable device communication or set up a firewall. However, when entering a school network or when in need of quickly using a café network, you can not be sure what level of network security is present. Thank you for your advice regarding the firewall, I will have a look at Gufw. Is there anything else that comes to your mind in that sense?

Comment: After networks, I generally do two things on laptops (but I am paranoid).  I choose to use full disk encryption during install.  This way, if my laptop is lost or stolen nobody can get at my data.  I also have it boot to a login prompt instead of straight to the desktop.  Encryption is only an option on install, unfortunately, and maybe not worth doing over.  For the login, go into Settings > System > User Accounts.  Hit unlock and make sure the "Automatic Login" is unset.

Lastly, I do not install Adobe Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its what your looking for, but i always install privacy badger on my Firefox to help get rid of potential trackers.
Hope i could help.

PS. privacy badger is multi browser: https://www.eff.org/privacybadger

Comment: Hi zx_exe, not exactly. I didn't exactly count tracking software as a security threat, it's more of a privacy infringement, I would say. I am a Privacy Badger user myself and have been for some months and I would definitely recommend the plugin as well.